# How to connect to my usb-to-serial thingy on OpenBSD

Tags: usb, openbsd, serial-port, printer

I have an old OpenBSD (5.0 GENERIC#43 i386) at a production site. Now I'm trying to connect a zebra-printer to it with a usb-to-serial cable without success. The issue is getting the device to exist and configured.

How do I do that? Or is it already there?

Some output:

```
foobar# dmesg
...
uplcom0 at uhub1 port 1 "Prolific Technology Inc. USB-Serial Controller D" rev 1.10/3.00 addr 2
ucom0 at uplcom0
...

foobar# usbdevs -d 
addr 1: EHCI root hub, Intel
  uhub0
addr 1: UHCI root hub, Intel
  uhub1
 addr 2: USB-Serial Controller D, Prolific Technology Inc.
   uplcom0
addr 1: UHCI root hub, Intel
  uhub2
 addr 2: Lexmark T630, Lexmark International
   ulpt0
 addr 3: USB Optical Mouse, Logitech
   uhidev0
addr 1: UHCI root hub, Intel
  uhub3

foobar# usbdevs -df /dev/usb1
addr 1: UHCI root hub, Intel
  uhub1
 addr 2: USB-Serial Controller D, Prolific Technology Inc.
   uplcom0

foobar# ls /dev/ucom0 /dev/uplcom0
ls: /dev/ucom0: No such file or directory
ls: /dev/uplcom0: No such file or directory
```

Note that the `ulpt0`-device is connected to a regular paper-printer and that is working properly, it is the `uplcom0`-device that I can't get to.

According to `man ucom` there seems to be some thing on `/dev/ttyU?`. I have also tried sending data to these with no success. On `/dev/ttyU0` I interrupt after waiting some minutes and get the message:

```
ksh: cannot create /dev/ttyU0: Interrupted system call
```

For the others `/dev/ttyU[1-3]` I get messages similar to this:

```
ksh: cannot create /dev/ttyU1: Device not configured
```

Comment: Do you have anything attaching as an `ulpt` device? (Reading again) Yes you have. Is that not your printer?

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. The `ulpt0`-device is a regular paper-printer, and that is working properly. It is the `uplcom0` that is connected to the zebra-label-printer, but I can not get to it.

Answer (score 2):

Read `man 4 ucom`. You are probably looking for `/dev/cuaU0` which is the "calling unit" (see `man 4 tty`) for the `ttyU0` terminal.

Try `# cu -s 115200 -l /dev/cuaU0` to see if you can chat with the printer.  Change the baud rate from 115200 to something else, if needed be (the default is 9600).

Also, remember that only `root` and users on the `dialer` group have permission to read/write to `/dev/cuaU0`, so you might want to add your user to the dialer group: `# usermod -G dialer foo`.